# Thread and Task scheduling

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have  a code which synchronize threads via `AutoResetEvent`

Basically there are two threads which swap control and execute commands  , each thread at a time.

**Code** :

```
static EventWaitHandle _waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
static void Waiter()
{

    _waitHandle.WaitOne();
    Console.WriteLine("A...");
    _waitHandle.Set();  
    _waitHandle.WaitOne();
    Console.WriteLine("A2...");
    _waitHandle.Set();
}

static void Waiter2()
{   
    _waitHandle.WaitOne();
    Console.WriteLine("B...");
    _waitHandle.Set();
    _waitHandle.WaitOne();
    Console.WriteLine("B2...");
}


void Main()
{
    new Thread(Waiter).Start();
    new Thread(Waiter2).Start();
   _waitHandle.Set(); // Wake up the Waiter.
}
```

**Result** : (I always get this result)

```
A...
B...
A2...
B2...
```

However - when I move to `Tasks` :

```
Task.Run(()=>Waiter());
Task.Run(()=>Waiter2());
```

I sometimes get :

```
B...
A...
B2...
```

Which is clear to me because the task scheduler scheduled the second task to execute first.

Which leads me to ask :

**Questions**

1) Do threads order guaranteed to be the same as order of invocation in :

```
new Thread(Waiter).Start();
new Thread(Waiter2).Start();
//In other words , will I always get the first result ?
```

2) How can I Force the  `Task.Run`s to be invoked the same order as I invoke them?

Comment: The order of execution is not guaranteed. Also, it's a very bad idea to have multiple threads waiting for the same `AutoResetEvent`, think about it... [This](http://blog.mikejmcguire.com/2014/12/22/using-the-autoresetevent-class-to-wake-multiple-threads-in-c/) is a good read.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, it is not guaranteed, you just got lucky that the output was the same every time.
2. Add in a 2nd `AutoResetEvent` that has a `WaitOne` between the two tasks and a `Set` in at the start of the `Waiter` method.

Comment: Scott , say i have 10 threads , not 2 , and i want the same thing - must i have 20 waithandles ?

Comment: No, you just need a WaitOne between each method and a Set at the start of each method using the same AutoResetEvent as the first WaitOne

Answer (score 3):

Without a synchronization mechanism, you cannot guarantee the order in which a thread will start and/or execute.  Furthermore, a thread's execution may be preempted (think: "paused") at any time.

So to answer your questions:

1. No
2. No

Before moving forward, you should ask yourself "Do I really need to use threads to solve this problem?"

My favorite quote from the Microsoft's MSDN:

> "When you use multithreading of any sort, you potentially expose yourself to very serious and complex bugs" [[Best Practices for Implementing the Event-based Asynchronous Pattern]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228974(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you do need to introduce threads, then I would begin by familiarizing yourself with some of Microsoft's synchronization mechanisms:

- [Critical Section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx)
- [Mutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx)
- Events

  - [Auto Reset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx)
  - [Manual Reset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: How does critical section relates here . ? Besides i don't see how your aside part contribute to your answer. It is not that I'm not familiar with the subject . I had a scheduling question . Thats all :-)

Comment: Your original question relates to thread synchronization mechanisms.  A critical section is one such example.

Comment: I disagree . Lock is ensuring one thread at a shared code section . I didn't have that problem.  But anyway ....